# How to scale an image and kepp the lines thickness?

Tags: css, animated-gif

I have a line art, an animated transparent gif on page, made in photoshop.

```
#img01{
    max-width:79%;
    max-height:79%;
    margin-top:3vh;
}
```

On small screen size (mobile), thickness of lines is too thin, and on screens over 1024px the lines are too thick ?
Is there a way to scale only the size of image, and keep the thickness of drawing ?

Comment: You cannot dynamically change the thickness of lines inside a GIF from CSS (or any other tech) without creating a new image.

Comment: @JoanCharmant, but I need what you say: NOT to change the thickness of lines dinamically.

Comment: (Keeping the same thickness when the whole image is resized is like changing the thickness in the image: not possible.). If it's reasonable, you could create several animated GIF beforehand for a few selected standard displays, and select the right GIF based on user-agent or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIF is a raster-based image format. There's no way to nicely (and automatically) modify an image like that. What you're looking for is a vector-based image/animation format.

There are two obvious candidates for this:

- Flash
- SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)

Comment: Animated SVG might not be very portable either…